# FormData и некорректный $_POST массив

Tags: jquery, formdata, php, http, ajax

Выполняя этот код

```
    $form.submit(function(event) {
        var formData = new FormData($form.get(0));

        $.ajax({
            url: 'add',
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
        }).done(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
        });

        function progressHandlingFunction(event) {
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                var $progBar = $('.progress-bar');
                $progBar.attr({ariaValuenow: event.loaded / event.total * 100, ariaValuemax: 100});
                $progBar.css('width', event.loaded / event.total * 100 + '%');
            }
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

получаем следующее. Это вывод *var_dump($_POST, $_FILES)*.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      '-----------------------------264085401441

Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name' => string '"movie_name"

name

-----------------------------264085401441

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="movie_desc"

-----------------------------264085401441

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="release_date"

-----------------------------264085401441--

' (length=265)
  1 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Из за чего такие приколы могут происходить?

Comment: @RubaXa спасибо вам огромное. Сделайте пожалуйста ответ, я его приму. Пол дня на эту дурню потратил :(
Хотя читал же описание свойства contentType. Там значение типа строка должно быть, а можете подсказать, что false означает.

Comment: @Jeremen1, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentType: false` — забыли

По умолчанию jQuery устанавливает его как "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", а вам нужен "multipart/form-data".

Comment: @RubaXa то есть false устанавливает его как multipart/form-data?